# Пунктуация в предложении В. Тендрякова

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, авторская-пунктуация

> Возраст автомашины измеряют не годами, а километрами. Тридцать тысяч на спидометре — считай, юность, начало жизни. ***А полуторка Васи Дергачева выглядела старухой: помятые крылья, расхлябанные, обшарпанные борта, погнут буфер, на выхлопе вылетает дымок со зловещей синевой: верный признак — страдает машина обычной автомобильной одышкой, сносились кольца.*** Укатали сивку крутые горки густоборовских дорог. Сейчас стоит она, постукивает моторами и мелко трясется всем своим многотерпеливым корпусом, словно страшится нового тяжкого испытания.
> [В. Ф. Тендряков. Ухабы](https://modernlib.net/books/tendryakov_vladimir_fedorovich/uhabi/read_1/)

Конечно же, я знаю, что предложений с двумя двоеточиями предостаточно.
Но в этом предложении *что-то* меня смущает.
А как бы вы расставили знаки? Всё ли здесь правильно?

Comment: Я бы поменял местами второе двоеточие и тире.

Comment: @Nektoid
А одышка к чему относится, только к дымку?  Если так, то  это не обозначено ни знаками, ни грамматикой.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы это написала так:

*А полуторка Васи Дергачева выглядела старухой: помятые крылья, расхлябанные, обшарпанные борта, погнут буфер; **на выхлопе вылетает дымок со зловещей синевой,** **а это вЕрный признак — страдает машина обычной автомобильной одышкой, сносились кольца.***

Пояснение

1. **Два двоеточия** мне никогда не нравились. Для меня это не чисто графический знак, а обозначение **интонации**. И вот две затянутые (предупредительные) паузы в предложении говорят о том, что там неудачно расставлены знаки и, соответственно, не лучшее прочтение.
2. **Точка с запятой** отделяет заключительную часть фразы (если одышка относится к дымку).
3. Вместо второго двоеточия используется **союзная связь**, а **тире** там на месте (ударение надает на "верный", поэтому паузу удобно обозначить тире).

Comment: Да, согласен точка с запятой тут уместна.